# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Tags: php, class, mysqli

I am using ajillion / PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class. I get an error when I try to update my data by using the `where` method with an `IN` clause.

Code I've used:

```
$samples = (1,2,3,4,5);    $mydb->where("psit_img_id",  array("in",
$samples));    $data = array("Sample"=>1);   
$mydb->update("ProcessDetail",$data);
```

Comment: ajillion's class is dirty, insecure and malfunctional.

Comment: I got it working by doing update of ajillion / PHP-MySQLi-Database new class.